# non login non interactive bash startup problem

Tags: bash

I was learning about startup files for bash and I found the following link :

[Explain bash startup files](https://zwischenzugs.com/2019/02/27/bash-startup-explained/)

Then at the last branch in the diagram in the link I found if the bash is non login non interactive then the env variables should be sourced by the environment variable BASH_ENV , I have made a test file and written BASH_ENV="/home/myusername/.bare.sh"

the contents of .bare.sh is :

```
var="the bare environment branch should be reached"
```

and launched a script that print var :

```
echo $var
```

but no output is written after launching the script

i expected it to print "the bare environment branch should be reached"

What could be the problem here ?

Comment: How are you executing the script? What shebang does it have?

Comment: How did you start the script and was it actually invoked with `bash` as its interpreter?

Comment: yes using bash .... #! /bin/bash

Comment: on redhat 7 linux

Comment: Please provide the complete sequence of actions: Where and how did you set `BASH_ENV`? What was the exact command used to run the script?

Comment: @muru thanks Kusalananda's answer solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the non-interactive, non-login, `bash` shell finds `BASH_ENV` *in its environment*, it will source that file.  If `BASH_ENV` is not exported, it will not be found in that shell's environment.

This means that you either have to `export BASH_ENV` in the calling shell, or use

```
BASH_ENV=$BASH_ENV ./myscript.sh
```

when starting the script.

Relevant passage from the `bash` manual:

> When bash is started non-interactively, to run a shell script, for
>          example, it looks for the variable `BASH_ENV` in the environment, expands
>          its value if it appears there, and uses the expanded value as the name
>          of a file to read and execute.  Bash behaves as if the following
>          command were executed:
>
> ```
> if [ -n "$BASH_ENV" ]; then . "$BASH_ENV"; fi
> ```
>
> but the value of the `PATH` variable is not used to search for the
>          filename.

So, in short, it's not enough to just set `BASH_ENV` in your interactive shell, it also has to be visible in the shell script's environment.

Comment: yes that worked great ... also using  export BASH_ENV=...etc before invocation of script

Answer (score 0):

Another case of non-interactive shell invocations are those by a remote shell daemon, usually `rshd`, or the secure shell daemon `sshd`. Quoting the forementioned [Bash Manual on startup files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html):

> If Bash determines it is being run non-interactively in this fashion,
> it reads and executes commands from ~/.bashrc, if that file exists and
> is readable.

In that case, it is sufficient to have a `~/.bashrc` like that:

```
 if [ -z "$POSIXLY_CORRECT" ]; then
     [ -z "$BASH_ENV" ] && export BASH_ENV="$HOME/.bash_env"
     source "$BASH_ENV"
 fi
```

For more details on bash startup files, a complete setup for all scenarios can be found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/758273/how-to-export-global-variables-to-child-process-in-bash/765305#answer-765305).