# How to export global variables to child process in bash

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I am using Arch and bash and Openbox window manager.
Everything is up to date.
Openbox is configured with a file called `rc.xml`

Within `rc.xml` I typically call `bash -c 'command1; command2; etc'`
to connect necessary useful command sequences to hotkeys.

I have a hotkey definition within `rc.xml` as follows

```
<keybind key="1"><action name="Execute"><command>bash -c '
command1;
command2;
etc;
yad --timeout=1 --text="$pos_x x $pos_y";
'</command></action></keybind>
```

and this all works as expected and is fully functional except that globally defined variables `$pos_x` and `$pos_y` don't show.

Within `.bashrc` these are defined as

```
export pos_x=1000  
export pos_y=500
```

and when I open a new bash shell terminal window and type
`echo "$pos_x x $pos_y"`
I see
1000 x 500
as expected.

But when in this new terminal window I type
`bash -c 'echo "$pos_x x $pos_y"'`
I see nothing, because apparently the child process does not inherit global variables.

If I type
`bash -c 'source ~/.bashrc; echo "$pos_x x $pos_y"'`
I see nothing, so sourcing .bashrc within the child process does not help.

How can I pass the global variables defined in `.bashrc` to the child process?

I had a look around and could nothing pointing to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

The default `~/.bashrc` on Arch contains these lines at the top of the file:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[[ $- != *i* ]] && return
```

This makes any non-interactive shell stop reading the file at that line. Since `bash -c` starts a non-interactive shell, the `~/.bashrc` file is not read in its entirety and that's why your variables aren't defined.

So, you can try:

1. Put the variable in `~/.profile` instead of `~/.bashrc`. This is the natural place for global variables anyway. As long as your login manager reads `/.profile`, this should work.
2. Use a different file. Instead of putting the variable definitions in `~/.bashrc`, just put them in `~/foo` and then make your command `bash -c '. ~/foo; echo "$pos_x x $pos_y"`.
3. Put the variable definitions above the line I showed at the beginning that stops the reading of `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: there's also `$BASH_ENV`, which, if set, tells Bash a file to read when starting to run a shell script. Of course that one isn't read for an interactive shell...

Answer (score 0):

From the [GNU Bash Manual, 6.2 Bash Startup Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html):

> **When Bash is invoked as an interactive login shell**, or as a non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and
> executes commands from the file `/etc/profile`, if that file exists.
> After reading that file, it looks for `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`,
> and `~/.profile`, in that order, and reads and executes commands from
> *the first one* that exists and is readable. ...
>
> **When Bash is started non-interactively**, to run a shell script, for example, it looks for the variable BASH_ENV in the environment,
> expands its value if it appears there, and uses the expanded value as
> the name of a file to read and execute.

So, to have the environment correctly set no matter if Bash is started interactively or non-interactively, it is not sufficient to have a `~/.bash_env`, you must also have the variable `BASH_ENV` set and pointing to it, and explicitly source it in interactive mode.

I'd put the Bash-specific stuff in Bash-specific files and leave the `~/.profile` for general settings that are still valid in other shells should you one day decide to change your login shell.

First, create a `~/.bash_profile` with the following contents:

```
 [ -f "$HOME/.profile" ] && source "$HOME/.profile"

 if [ -z "$POSIXLY_CORRECT" ]; then
     [ -z "$BASH_ENV" ] && export BASH_ENV="$HOME/.bash_env"
     source "$BASH_ENV"
 fi
```

Then create a file `"$HOME/.bash_env"` with all Bash-specific variables and functions.

Order matters: Putting the line that sources `~/.profile` at the top of `~/.bash_profile` enables you to override variables defined therein when running Bash.

I haven't checked whether the file referenced by the `BASH_ENV` variable is sourced when invoked by remote shell daemon, usually `rshd`, or the secure shell daemon `sshd`. Quoting the Bash Manual again,

> If Bash determines it is being run non-interactively in this fashion,
> it reads and executes commands from `~/.bashrc`, if that file exists and
> is readable.

it may be a good idea to also create a `~/.bashrc` with the following contents:

```
 if [ -z "$POSIXLY_CORRECT" ]; then
     [ -z "$BASH_ENV" ] && export BASH_ENV="$HOME/.bash_env"
     source "$BASH_ENV"
 fi
```

In that case, you can simplify the `~/.bash_profile`:

```
 [ -f "$HOME/.profile" ] && source "$HOME/.profile"
 [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ] && source "$HOME/.bashrc"
```

Finally, you want to have some protection guard against multiple inclusion in your `~/.bash_env`:

```
[ -n "$BASH_ENV_VERSION" ] && return 0
BASH_ENV_VERSION=.....

...
```

Note: There is no point in `export`ing the variable (or any variable in the whole file) because the `~/.bash_env` script needs to be sourced for function definitions to become accessible in the current shell. For the same reason, none of the files that we've created needs a shebang line.

We treated interactive login-shells and non-interactive shells. An attentive reader might object that the missing piece are interactive non-login-shells. Luckily, these are covered by the steps above:

> When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, Bash
> reads and executes commands from ~/.bashrc, if that file exists.